# Windsor container registration

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I cant seem to get the proper service to configure.

The idea is to register all types that have the marker interface IDao and have there base classes be the service.

base class

```
public abstract class DirectorDaoContract : RepositoryBase<Director>
{
    public abstract Director Get(int id);
}
```

implementing class
     public class DirectorDao : DirectorDaoContract,IDao
    {

```
    public override Director Get(int directorId)
    {
    .....
    }
}
```

The Idea being that a

```
Resolve<DirectorDaoContract>()
```

would return DirectorDao

my current attempt

```
 container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(dataAssembly)
      .BasedOn<IDao>)
      .WithService.Base()
      .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerThread));
```

No matter what I have tried I am unable to get the service correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(dataAssembly)
      .BasedOn<IDao>()
      .WithService.FromInterface()
      .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerThread));
```

Comment: this registers the actual type not the base as the service

Comment: Yeah, I missed the part where you mention `DirectorDao`  (your formatting is messed up). Anyway, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(dataAssembly(
  .BasedOn(typeof(DirectorDaoContract))
  .WithService.Select((t,b) => t.GetInterfaces().Where(d => d == typeof(IDao)).AsEnumerable<Type>());
```

Comment: this would require I register all base types individuality.  The goal is to register types based on the marker interface.